# Set Custom icon to context menu for multiple charts (Highcharts)

Tags: highcharts

I want to apply a custom image to a context menu for multiple charts, This is the code I found to apply a custom image to a context menu. Here is [the link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/buttons-contextbutton-symbol-custom/)

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.download = function(x, y, w, h) {
  var path = [
    // Arrow stem
    'M', x + w * 0.5, y,
    'L', x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.7,
    // Arrow head
    'M', x + w * 0.3, y + h * 0.5,
    'L', x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.7,
    'L', x + w * 0.7, y + h * 0.5,
    // Box
    'M', x, y + h * 0.9,
    'L', x, y + h,
    'L', x + w, y + h,
    'L', x + w, y + h * 0.9
  ];
  return path;
};


Highcharts.chart('container', {
exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        symbol: 'download'
      }
    }
  }

});
```

This code snippet changes the symbol based on the unique id, How do i apply the same across multiple charts whose unique id is not known?

Answer (score 0):

The example which you have shared defines this symbol as a 'download' which saves this symbol in the Highcharts core options and makes it possible to get it whenever you want to use it, even multiple times.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7rt21zLe/

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.download = function (x, y, w, h) {
    var path = [
        // Arrow stem
        'M', x + w * 0.5, y,
        'L', x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.7,
        // Arrow head
        'M', x + w * 0.3, y + h * 0.5,
        'L', x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.7,
        'L', x + w * 0.7, y + h * 0.5,
        // Box
        'M', x, y + h * 0.9,
        'L', x, y + h,
        'L', x + w, y + h,
        'L', x + w, y + h * 0.9
    ];
    return path;
};
```